# What is the internal file format of a .glink file?

Tags: google-drive-api

I would like to add URL links into a web-based Google Drive folder. Searching online, it appears that this was once possible with files that ended in a .glink extension. I'm looking for documentation on the file format so that I can create them programmatically.

[EDIT] Why do I want to create .glink files? Because I want links (bookmarks, URLs) to be able to appear in my Google Drive web page and to be able to click on them an go to the page. Microsoft OneDrive supports this functionality.

Comment: Have you tested the option to use "Save to Google Drive" extension to view if it saves an specific file type when right clicking a hyperlink?  https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/save-to-google-drive/gmbmikajjgmnabiglmofipeabaddhgne

Comment: I don't understand: what should happen when you try to open the URL link from within the web interface of GDrive?

Comment: @cyberbrain - I edited the question to answer your question.

Comment: You could develop a Google Drive application that opens certain file types as you want that, although it might not be universally available if you don't use Google Workspace.

Comment: Seems bogus. I just want to be able to click on an link and open the URL, like I can in OneDrive. That's why I want to be able to create the `.glink` files. My hope is that some of the functionality still remains.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**GLINKS Files**

The URL link file feature was available due to a workaround with Back Up and Sync before being deprecated with Drive for Desktop. The .glink seems to be patched and no longer available as it was also part of a third party tool no longer available. It seems it now only saves them as .URL and automatically gives it the icon for Google Docs, as it would take it as a simple file with text.

Checking the .url type file of Windows, when uploading to Drive it does not update as it should, even utilizing Drive for Desktop (as an alternative to sync data like back up and sync) the outcome is the one suggested above.

This is the main reason why there is no longer any documentation about the matter, due to this one not being an official feature and being also fully deleted, it can be confirm by the file type available when creating files with the Drive API:

- https://developers.google.com/drive/api/guides/ref-export-formats

I would suggest to request a feature to allow this or to provide a new way to store URL links as before or report it to review if possible any references on how it used to work by submitting a feature request or checking the issue tracker about the matter:

- https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/new?component=191650&template=824106

You can also add the details of the previous threads or discussions about the `GLINKS`.

Comment: Thanks.  I have noticed that with the new Google Drive, some files just don't even get uploaded. I'll submit a request.